# Return values as multiple rows from a single column using pattern match?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query
SELECT TOP 1 text FROM [pageContent] WHERE pageid = 5

to return a field having the below value,

```
<table style="width: 100%;border:none !important">
        <tr style="border:none !important">
            <td style="border:none !important">

**[[http://mypage.com/123/data1|data1]]**

**[[http://mypage.com/345/data2|data2]]**

**[[http://mypage.com/567/data3|data3]]**

          </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

What i want is to return the data that starts with `'**[['` and ends with `']]**'`
returned as 3 rows. Something like the below,

[image]

1. What i have tried so far is replace the whole html tags with empty string and used a split function got from internet.
2. Strip out the html content using a function and split the content using split function.

What i want to know is, is there a way to to pattern match the field so that if a line contains a string starts with `'**[['` and ends with `']]**'` and return as multiple rows.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anytime you want to change row values into columns, you probably want to use the PIVOT function.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx  or are you confusing rows and columns?  your example shows 3 rows of data with 1 (unnamed) column.  Are you sure you don't want your results displayed how they are as Rows?

Comment: sorry. corrected the typo.

Comment: What you're really asking for here seems to be a "multi-line aware regular expression matcher", which you cannot do in pure SQL. You could write a C# CLR function that could be called from SQL, or you could actually do the processing in a C# program or utility... but if not, you'll be stuck with using REPLACE and a string splitter to patch together something that works for your specific data.

Comment: You can extract the items by running it through a split function with ']]**' as the row terminator, then doing a SUBSTRING() on the rows returned something like this: `IF CHARINDEX( '**[[', RowData) > 1 SET RowData = Substring(RowData, CHARINDEX( '**[[', RowData), LEN(RowData)) ELSE SET RowData = NULL -- Or ''` Then you add non-empty rows, stripping off delimiters as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string splitter is the way to go, but if you do it right, you don't need to care about the html at all:

First, create the split string function. I've used a function based on Jeff Moden's split strings taken from Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) article:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;

GO
```

Then, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE pageContent
(
    [text] varchar(1000),
    pageid int
)

INSERT INTO pageContent VALUES
('<table style="width: 100%;border:none !important">
        <tr style="border:none !important">
            <td style="border:none !important">

**[[http://mypage.com/123/data1|data1]]**

**[[http://mypage.com/345/data2|data2]]**

**[[http://mypage.com/567/data3|data3]]**

          </td>
      </tr>
</table>', 5)
```

Now, for the query I've used [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) and a derived table based on the query you posted in the question:

```
SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) As Content
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 text FROM [pageContent] WHERE pageid = 5
) query
CROSS APPLY
dbo.SplitStrings(text, char(10))
WHERE Item LIKE '%**%**%'
```

Results:

```
Content
**[[http://mypage.com/123/data1|data1]]**
**[[http://mypage.com/345/data2|data2]]**
**[[http://mypage.com/567/data3|data3]]**
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/RZI47101)